# Prove: $\frac{1}{a^2+bc}+\frac{1}{b^2+ca}+\frac{1}{c^2+ab}+\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+9abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\ge4$

Tags: inequality

> Let $a,b,c\ge0: (ab)^2+(bc)^2+(ca)^2=1.$ Prove that: $$\frac{1}{a^2+bc}+\frac{1}{b^2+ca}+\frac{1}{c^2+ab}+\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+9abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\ge4$$

My approach using well- known inequality:

For all $a,b,c\ge0$ then: $$\frac{1}{a^2+bc}+\frac{1}{b^2+ca}+\frac{1}{c^2+ab}\ge\frac{3}{ab+bc+ca}$$ It implies that we need to prove: $$\sqrt{a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2}\frac{3}{ab+bc+ca}+\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+9abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\ge4$$ But this one is not true for $(a,b,c)=(0,9;0,5;\dfrac{11}{28})$

I hope we can find a good way to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Equality holds for $a=b=1$ and $c=0$, and permutations.

Comment: Can you help me?

Comment: It is my homework. I really stuck

Comment: $$\frac{a}{a^{2}+bc}\ge\frac{3ab+3ca-a^{2}-bc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}$$ it is my teacher's hint but I still can not use it effectively

Answer (score 1):

Now, I have a partly solution due to my teacher's hint.Using the following one:

$$\frac{a}{a^{2}+bc}\ge\frac{3ab+3ca-a^{2}-bc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}$$$$\iff (a^2+bc -ab-ac)^2 \geq 0$$
$$\implies \frac{a^2}{a^{2}+bc}\ge\frac{3a^2b+3ca^2-a^{3}-abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}$$ Hence $$ \frac{a^2}{a^{2}+bc}+ \frac{b^2}{b^{2}+ca}+ \frac{c^2}{c^{2}+ab}+\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3+9abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\ge3$$
Now, we need to prove that: $$\frac{1-a^2}{a^2+bc}+\frac{1-b^2}{b^2+ca}+\frac{1-c^2}{c^2+ab}\ge1 (*)$$
But how to prove this nice one and using the original condition?

Edit: (*) is equivalent to: $$\sum_{cyc}{\frac{a^2(b^2+c^2)\left(b^2+c^2-a^2-2bc\right)^2}{(a^2+bc)\left(a^2+b^2+c^2+(b^2+c^2-a^2)bc+2a^2(b^2+c^2)\right)}}\ge0$$

I see a similar problem on [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2757436_a_beauty_1_amp0) which help very well. Also, I hope to see more approach for (*).

Comment: Have you managed to complete it?

Comment: It completed my approach. I edited

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your equivalent equation: how is equivalent to $(*)$ ? - are the left hand sides proportional, when $(*)$ could be written in the form $\sum_{cyc} \frac{3-4a^2-bc}{a^2+bc} \ge 0$ ? And how is it ensured that your equivalent equation is positive? [It would be sufficient that single terms $b^2+c^2-a^2 \ge0$ under the given boundary, but this is not the case ]-> so the argument must be more complicated.

Comment: It is result of software. But I think your mean is that LHS (*) is equivalent to $$\sum\frac{1+bc}{a^2+bc}\ge4$$

Comment: Well, for equivalence both versions have to be $\ge 0$ and then the two LHS must follow from each other by  "proportionality", meaning that the quotient can be a positive constant or a functional term which is positive for all admissible choices of the variables. I don't get this from your answer.

Comment: Now, I get a very nice supporting idea: $$\frac{1-a^2}{a^2+bc}\ge\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}$$ which is obvious! This is the key to open the problem.